# spring boot starter web @ControllerAdvice annotation is not work without having @RestController annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**RESOLVE**

in rest api application, the return type of exception handling method should be `ResponseEntity` or annotate the method with `@ResponseBody` so that spring boot can do the http serialisation.

**UPDATE**

starter class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableTransactionManagement//TODO remove this line if not needed
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

private static Class<Application> applicationClass= Application.class;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(applicationClass);
}
}
```

I was using `@ControllerAdvice` to handle global exception handling in spring boot starter web and I got such a weird problem.

As I followed the guide from spring official doc, https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc, to handling exceptions globally, just add a handler class with `@ControllerAdivce` annotated. But, when I test it, the exception handling method is not invoked when a `RunTimeException` is thrown.

Here is My code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(value = RuntimeException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public RestEntity handleException(HttpServletRequest req, RuntimeException ex) {
    RestEntity restEntity=new RestEntity();
    Message message=new Message();
    message.setCode(1000);
    message.setMessage("Something wrong with the server");
    restEntity.setMessage(message);
    return restEntity;
}
}
```

And I have methods in other controllers annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` to handle specific exceptions in each Controller, while leave unresolved exceptions to the `GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler`.

It turns out that it doesn't work. Am I missing something here??

And, for now, as a workaround , I just add `@RestControoler` on the `GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler` and it just work fine. I don't why...

Anyone can help?

Comment: Post some configuration.

Comment: M. Deinum I don't have much configuration, just a application.properties, which only contains some database configuration, redis configuration and logging configuration. Nothing is related with the exception handling logic

Comment: At least add something, a starter class etc. a `@ControllerAdvice` is a `@Component` so it should be detected so you must have somewhere disabled proper component-scanning.

Comment: M. Deinum I add the starter class as above. But, I think I've figured it out myself... I tried change the return type of the exception handling method `handleException` to `ResponseEntity<RestEntity>`, it worked again... Springboot must have to wrap the return type of exception handler method, without a `ResponseEntity`, springboot just ignore the return type and give the default response object structure, with timestamp, error message, url and etc...

Comment: Instead of that you could also have added `@ResponseBody` as that is what you want.

Comment: Also, you don't need both @ SpringBootApplication and @ ComponentScan,
@ EnableAutoConfiguration together. Use either one.

Comment: Do you have a particular controller in your project (another class annotated with @RestController)?

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to remove @EnableWebMvc from my main application file.

Here the working configuration for me:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
....
})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { ... }
```

and the ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandlingController { ... }
```